# Can't remove a entire command in iTerm and Terminal on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

I'm using iTerm and Terminal in Mac OS X El Captain.

When I delete characters using "delete" button in the command line, it stuck at some point and don't move left further in both iTerm and Terminal.

For example, I typed

`%ps -aef | grep test`

and then tried to remove this command entirely from the last char using "delete" button.

But when I removed until e and I still had

`%ps -a`

and then stuck and couldn't remove from a. I can't completely remove the entire command.
It happens so frequently and very annoying.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Someone already replied and asked some and this is my reply:

- `export PS1="\e[\033[35m[\u:\W]\$ \e[m "` in .bash_profile
- `echo $TERM` output is `xterm-256color`  delete
- delete key is backspace key on mac book air

Comment: This sounds similar to what happens when your prompt is misconfigured and `bash` doesn't know how long it actually is. What is the value of `PS1`?

Comment: wrong terminal-type? `echo $TERM` ? For the `delete` mean `backspace`? What happens when you press `CTRL-C`?

Answer (score 0):

In your prompt

```
export PS1="\e[\033[35m[\u:\W]\$ \e[m "
```

bash does not know that the *printable* part is only

```
export PS1="[\u:\W]\$  "
```

Unless told otherwise, by bracketing the nonprintable characters with `\[` and `\]`, it assumes the whole string is printable, counting each ordinary character as one column (*`\u`* and *`\W`* mean something that the shell computes for itself).

You might have meant something like this:

```
export PS1="\[\033[35m\][\u:\W]\$ \[\e[m\] "
```

(trimming the spurious **`\e[`** which does nothing useful).